# Remove map-content space on contacts page

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-us

I have a theme my mom bought and for the contacts page they had a map-content static block but I deleted it because I don't want a map but I see that there is still a space on the contacts page for it. How can I remove this space?

See link https://www.discreetlynice.co.za/english/contacts/

Comment: Which magento version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit css file:
https://www.discreetlynice.co.za/skin/frontend/default/theme600/css/styles.css

and comment code of 2 css classes ( like below )

```
.map-content {
/* margin-bottom: 30px; */
/* padding-bottom: 50%; */
}
styles.css:1765
.video, .map-content {
   /* height: 100%; */
   position: relative;
   /* padding-bottom: 56.25%; */
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Must it be like you have done?

Comment: @Storm, you can just edit  .map-content class ( line number 1768 of your file ) and change values to margin-bottom: 0px ;  padding-bottom: 0%;

Comment: this is not a proper solution by this way you just make that portion hidden but it is still present their